# Dualboot with Asus Zenbook Flip

Tags: boot, dual-boot, asus

I bought an Asus Zenbook Flip (i7, 16 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD) with Windows 10 on it.
Now there is the problem that you can't enter the BIOS with keys at startup anymore (or am I wrong?). I managed to enter BIOS on Menu -> Setting -> Update and Security -> and so on. Then I installed Ubuntu 18 on a space of 300 GB.
Now Ubuntu is on the second priority of the boot.

The problem:
If I change the priority of the boot to Ubuntu as #1 and Windows at #2, I don't know how to change that again after entering Ubuntu. How should I enter the boot menu so that I can enter Windows again? Because with the keys at Startup it is not possible.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Best regards
Sero

Answer (score 0):

Here it says you can access it with:

```bsh
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

- [Linux on UEFI - how to reboot to the UEFI setup screen like Windows 8 can? | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/519718/linux-on-uefi-how-to-reboot-to-the-uefi-setup-screen-like-windows-8-can)
- [`systemctl` | freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--firmware-setup)

Comment: Tried it worked for me. I'm running Xubuntu 18.04 on a old Asus VIVObook, where I changed the HDD to SSD.